# Pick up any element in SQL "group by"

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have flight records for itinerary and there is guaranty that all prices for selected itinerary are in same currency.

With `group by` query I get total `sum` of itinerary price:

```
select ITINERARY_ID, sum(PRICE) from FLIGHT group by ITINERARY_ID;
```

How can I pick currency (they all the same for given `ITINERARY_ID`)?

I end with `min`/`max`:

```
select ITINERARY_ID, sum(PRICE), max(CURRENCY) from FLIGHT group by ITINERARY_ID;
```

but it is not wise to sort `CURRENCY` if I only want to pick **any** element up (they all the same).

Is `min`/`max` only the possible solution? Can query performance be improved?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Oracle but it is behind Hibernate ORM. Is window function is a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 3):

> (they all the same for given ITINERARY_ID)

You don't need to aggregate it then, you can write your query as

```
select  ITINERARY_ID, CURRENCY, sum(PRICE)
from    FLIGHT
group by ITINERARY_ID, CURRENCY
```

Comment: `group by` on two fields has same performance as `group by` on one + `max` on second, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I suppose performance would be the same. I don't think there's much room to optimize such a simple query in that sense though, you may consider using indexes instead

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is in the table design. You say it is *guaranteed* that all prices for an itinerary are in same currency. But you store the currency per flight which technically allows for *different* currencies within an itinerary.

Store the currency with the itinerary instead and query accordingly:

```
select i.itinerary_id, f.total_price, i.currency
from itinerary i
join 
(
  select itinerary_id, sum(price) as total_price
  from flight
  group by itinerary_id
) f on f.itinerary_id = i.itinerary_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include `currency` in the `group by`:

```
select ITINERARY_ID, currency, sum(PRICE)
from FLIGHT
group by ITINERARY_ID, currency;
```

Or use an aggregation function:

```
select ITINERARY_ID, MAX(currency) as currency, sum(PRICE)
from FLIGHT
group by ITINERARY_ID;
```

If the currencies are indeed the same, then these produce the same results.

Comment: Is your second query have typo? You group on the same element on which aggregation function is applied...